# What does the term ‘fully-converged’ mean?

Tags: networking

What does the term ‘fully-converged’ mean in networking? and again what does it mean "Prone to looping due to convergence".
Im reading about different protocols like R.I.P, OSPF, BGP, and I didn't really understand those terms.
Im looking around but I can't find any specific answers about it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a network contains layer 2 and layer 3 devices, then this devices takes some time to 'understand' the topology of the network.
This is done when the layer 3 devices builds up a table ( routing table) based on the various routes, may be static, dynamic or directly connected routes. This table develops until the complete topology of the network is mapped out in the routing table. Then we can say the network is fully-converged.

Answer (score 0):

Routing-management protocols like [RIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_Information_Protocol), [OSPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Shortest_Path_First), and [BGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol) are all about the distribution of information about network paths between and among network nodes. All such protocols tend to have a model where each node has its own view of what some or all of the network-path topology looks like.  The nodes exchange information to drive all nodes to a common, "converged", view of the network.  A "fully converged" network is one in which all the nodes fully understand the paths through it.